# Plotting a 3D surface in its true ratios

Tags: plotting

```
GR1 = Plot3D[Cos[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, -0.3, 0.3} , 
  PlotLabel -> corrugation, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
GR2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Cos[x]}, {x, - Pi , Pi}, {y, 
   0.3, -0.3} , Mesh -> { 60, 5},  PlotLabel -> Single]
```

When physical object has changed its length (thrice here) is there a way to plot its 3D image so that we have domain proportions true to plotted lengths along each of the three axes?

Comment: I am really confused.  What exactly you are looking for?

Comment: The box length proportion for GR1  should be $ x:y:z= 6 \pi : 0.6 : 2 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is give the `BoxRatios` option the ratios you mention in the comment.

```
Plot3D[Cos[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, -0.3, 0.3},
  PlotLabel -> "corrugation",
  MeshStyle -> None,
  Boxed -> False,
  Axes -> None,
  BoxRatios -> {6 Pi, .6, 2}]
```

[image: corrugation]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html) setting for the [`BoxRatios`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html) option.

```
Plot3D[Cos[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, -0.3, 0.3},
 PlotLabel -> "corrugation",
 MeshStyle -> None,
 Boxed -> False,
 Axes -> None,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `BoxRatios -> Automatic` *Mathematica* determines the ratios from the domain of the variables and the range of the function on that domain.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably BoxRatios is the option you are looking for:

```
GR2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, Cos[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, 0.3, -0.3}, 
  Mesh -> {60, 5}, PlotLabel -> Single, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```